# Plans for hierarchical view culling in three.js?

Tags: three.js

Are there plans to add hierarchical view culling in three.js? Specifically would each Object3D parent have its own bounding sphere for all child Object3D objects. Digging in the three.js code it appears only the bounding sphere of the geometry on a Mesh is checked.

I have an app that requires deep zooms and level of detail changes. Currently I am hacking a hierarchical cull by doing my own bounding sphere calculation and culling by removing children from Object3D.

Here is a sample of what I'm building.
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s43/sh/5fb37faf-6b71-4049-97b8-8c041251e7d1/220232188045cef57bacd3e243380500

Comment: This is not the correct board to be asking about future three.js development plans. Instead, you can file a feature request on the three.js github issues [board](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues?sort=updated&state=open).

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a feature request.